# Updating notification Center

Tags: ios, swift, time

I'm having an issue with my notification center in swift.
I'm trying to make an updating bus schedule viewed from the notification center of iPhone, so you don't have to enter the app to see the next bus time.
FOR EXAMPLE:

If the time on your phone is >= to 11:30 and <= 11:59

```
print "next bus is 12:00"
```

if  the time on your phone is >= 12:00 and <= 12:29

```
print "next bus is at 12:30
```

etc.

I want it to constantly update itself, as if its in a loop. Can anybody help me with the code?

Comment: What's the user input? What's the algorithm of showing notifications? Why `UILocalNotification` can't deal with your problem? Please provide more details and code.

Comment: Is this a notification center today extension or are you trying to send a local notification?

Comment: it is a notification center today extension .

Answer (score 1):

As Noir hints in his/her comment, the way for your app to post notifications to the notification center is by creating and posting local notifications. If your app is not running in the foreground, the notification is displayed to the user in the notification center.

You can submit local notifications with `fireDate` values in the future and they will trigger on their specified fireDate.

### EDIT:

Do you want notifications to show up in the system notification center, or do you want your app to show a list of upcoming bus times, and update itself while the user is looking at it? The notification center isn't really intended for a calendar of upcoming events, but rather for alarms and "you got this message" type notifications.

Comment: this is the code i have so far. 

repeat {
            
           if (dateComponents.hour == 17 && dateComponents.minute >= 0 && dateComponents.minute < 30){
                Label.text = "next bus is at 5:30";
            print("it works");
        
            }
        } while (flag == 0)

Comment: okay, well how can i fix it then. I'm a beginner swift programmer fresh out of college so I'm still learning everything..

Comment: By using local notifications as I told you in my answer. Apple does not allow apps to run continuously in the background. It drains the user's battery too fast.

Comment: i want the notification to show up in my notification center. a looping bus schedule that updates itself based on your phones time, so if its currently 12:00. and the next bus is at 12:30, itll say the "next bus:12:30" and when 12:30 rolls around, itll display the NEXT bus time.